# How to use a Handler in a Broadcast Receiver?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-activity, handler, delay

I tried to use a Handler object in my Broadcast Receiver because I need some code to be executed with a slight delay but it never gets called. I guess that's because there is no activity (thread) to manage the message queue because the Broadcast Receiver is called not by an activity but by the system while there is no activity of this app running on the device. The Broadcast Receiver is registered in the app's manifest file and filters for one of the system intents. How to use the Handler in such a case? Do I have to create a new thread programatically just for the Handler object to be executed?

Comment: Which events your receiver gets? Add some code, it's quite hard to understand what do you mean.

Comment: My receiver filters for ON_BOOT_COMPLETED intent and then I want it to display a toast message after i. e. 20 seconds. So I use the myHandler.postMessageDelayed() method and in the Handler object's handleMessage() method I display the toast message. It works perfectly if I start an acitivity before calling the Handler object, but otherwise it is never called. Sorry but I can't put any code because I'm not using my pc right now. This is insanely easy and I don't think my code would be helpful.

Comment: Just a simple instance of the Handler class `Handler myHandler = new Handler () {...};`

Comment: it wont work then, it could work, but im not 100% sure if the. Handler was cre!ted in Applicarion object for example, see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html#ReceiverLifecycle

Comment: But I just said that it works perfectly if I start an activity before calling the sendMessageDelayed() method so it works. But I don't want to start an activity just to execute the handler...